# Find all records which have no associated records within rich join table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Here are my models:

```
class Complaint < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :complaints_problem_areas
  has_many :problem_areas, through: :complaints_problem_areas
end

# rich join table for complaints and problem areas
class ComplaintsProblemArea < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :complaint
  belongs_to :problem_area
end

class ProblemArea < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :complaints_problem_areas
  has_many :complaints, through: :complaints_problem_areas
end
```

I want to grab all the `Complaints` that do not have any associated `problem areas`.

I think the solution might have something with a left join?  Something like this (though this doesn't appear to work)

```
complaints = Complaint.all.joins(:complaints_problem_area).where(problem_area_id: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, a `LEFT JOIN` should solve this:

```
Complaint.
  joins('LEFT JOIN complaints_problem_areas ON complaints.id = complaints_problem_areas.complaint_id').
  where('complaints_problem_areas.problem_area_id IS NULL')
```

`joins(:complaints_problem_area)` does not work, because it generates an `INNER JOIN`.  You want a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a `left join` query with ActiveRecord methods instead of raw sql, using `includes`:

```
Complaint.includes(:complaints_problem_areas)
         .where(complaints_problem_areas: {problem_area_id: nil})
         .references(:complaints_problem_areas)
```